# How to adjust IntelliJ Scala formatting of multiple parameter lists

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm trying to follow a coding style that requires (don't ask me why)

```
def foo(
    arg11: Int,
    arg12: Int
  )(arg21: String,
    arg22: String
  ): Int
```

What I get with the default styling is:

```
def foo(
    arg11: Int,
    arg12: Int
)(
    arg21: String,
    arg22: String
): Int
```

I can not figure out how to make:
- first param of 2nd-nth parameter list be on the same line as the opening paren
- the `)(` line(s) be indented two spaces.
- the `):` line be indented two spaces.

I don't know that these elements even *get* their own styling rules.

I can see the value of these style rules but manually reformatting spaces all over my code isn't what I expected to be doing in 2016!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scalafmt plugin to configure your formatting style you need to simply give configuration file according to your formatting style and it will format your code accordingly please check this out https://olafurpg.github.io/scalafmt/